# Sentence Construction: clauses

Tags: syntactic-analysis

What are the subjects, verbs and objects in this sentence?
Is it a sentence with two independent clauses?

**Anybody who changed jobs too many times risked being seen as a “flake.”**

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand your explanation

Answer (score -1):

*main clause*:                                    Anybody … risked being seen as a “flake"
(*or independent clause ([ref.](https://www.chompchomp.com/terms/mainclause.htm)*))
*subject*:                                             anybody
*verb*:                                                 risked
*object*:                                              being seen as a "flake"

*relative clause*:                             who changed jobs too many times
*subject*:                                           who
*verb*:                                               changed
*object*:                                              jobs

Since there are two conjugated verbs there must be two clauses; since there is a relative pronoun, one of the clauses must be a relative clause, which makes the other one a main clause. It follows that according to the alternative terminology in which main clauses are called also independent clauses, there is one independent clause.  Two independent clauses would be connected either by a conjunction or by *parataxis* (a comma, a semi-colon) ([ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parataxis#Description)). There does not exist a grammatical relation of dependence of one on the other between independent clauses: this means that you can suppress the conjunction or the comma and the two groups of words that result are correct sentences. The same principle is true for independent clauses of the type called "main": they must stand on their own after the dependent clauses have been removed.